# Proving every set with left identity and inverse is a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> Prove that set with closure over the binary operation, associativity, unique left identity and unique left inverse for every element is a group.

My solution: I will prove that no two elements have the same inverse. If $ma=mb=e$, then multiplying by $m^{-1}$ on both sides we get $a=b$, which is a contradiction.

So now we know two things.Every element has a unique left inverse, and no elements elements have the same left inverse. Hence if we have a mapping $f:S\to S$ such that $f(a)=a^{-1}$, then this mapping will be **bijective**.

Hence, as every element if the left inverse of some element, all elements also have unique right inverses.

Now take $a.e=aa^{-1}a=e.a$, proving every element is commutative with the left identity.

I am aware that solutions exist to this problem on the site. I would just be interested in finding out the mistake in my reasoning.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion that $f$ is bijective needs more proof than what you gave. You only showed it is injective. It thus does not follows that every element is the left inverse of some element, and thus you did not establish that every element also has a right inverse.

Comment: Let us suppose $|S|=n$. And every element has a unique left inverse within $S$ that it does not share with any other element. Then the number f left inverses=$n$. Doesn't this prove bijectivity?

Comment: yes, an injective function $f:S\to S$ where $S$ is a finite set is also surjective.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not able to completely follow your objection. Wouldn't injectivity and surjecttivity together prove bijectivity?

Comment: but it is not assumed that $S$ is finite.

Comment: Also, I just found out that this argument does not work in the "clearly wrong" situation I was talking about. So this argument needn't necessarily be flawed.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Regardless, the set $S$ is not necessarily finite and therefore the injective function $f$ is not necessarily surjective.

Comment: oh LOL I just meant that my argument is wrong not because of the reasons that I intitially thought up, but because of the reasons that you have just given. Thanks for your help.